# WSDL: Can't figure out the parameter for method

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I've been googling around for two days with no luck, hoping directly asking the question would shed light!

I'm working on a stock level update system with a fulfilment company. I've been given the wsdl address and the following instructions:

> When calling a command, the website must pass the command name to the web service as well as a list
>   of parameters. The parameters must be formatted in the following way:

```
<params>
<ParamName>Value</ParamName>
<AnotherParam>Value</AnotherParam>
</params>
```

> **GetStock** - Get available stock levels for a given supplier
>
> Parameter Datatype Comments
>
> ClientCode  String
>   SupplierCode    String  Leave blank or exclude
>   parameter for all stock levels for the client

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetStock>
  <StockLevels>
    <Stock>
      <Sku>12848</Sku>
      <AltSku></AltSku>
      <SupplierCode>0044</SupplierCode>
      <Description>Australia Toggle £20 credit SIM</Description>
      <InStock>1</InStock>
      <Allocated>2</Allocated>
      <Available>17</Available>
      <Prices></Prices>
    </Stock>
  </StockLevels>
</GetStock>
```

I managed to get my SoapClient working, authenticating and getting a token back (after receiving authentication errors). I couldn't call GetStock so I used __getFunctions() and figured I need to use the GetData() method.

Looking up the WSDL file I found the following:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.mnp-main.com/OMSConnect/IDataFeed/GetData" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Now I'm completely stumped as to what to do! I know GetStock is not an available method so it has to be done via GetData, but I just can't figure out what parameters to pass through it.

The only thing I've figured out is that the second parameter for GetData is the auth token, but the first part - whatever I put it results in the following message:

> End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 174.

Looking through the schema file hasn't shed any light for me at all either :(

I apologise if I'm missing something very obvious but I've had no former training on this and all the tutorials I came across seem to have clear method name and params in the wsdl file, unlike what I've got here.

Many thanks for your help!

**Update 2:**

Here's the __getFunctions and __getTypes results:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(59) "AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(Authenticate $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(44) "GetDataResponse GetData(GetData $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(74) "GetDataWithParamsResponse GetDataWithParams(GetDataWithParams $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(68) "ValidateSessionResponse ValidateSession(ValidateSession $parameters)"
  [4]=>
  string(53) "ClearCacheResponse ClearCache(ClearCache $parameters)"
  [5]=>
  string(53) "GetVersionResponse GetVersion(GetVersion $parameters)"
  [6]=>
  string(77) "GetImageWithResizeResponse GetImageWithResize(GetImageWithResize $parameters)"
}
```

For GetData and GetDataWithParams:

```
[10]=>
  string(55) "struct GetData {
  string command;
  string tokenValue;
}"
[11]=>
  string(56) "struct GetDataResponse {
  ResultGetData GetDataResult;
}"
[12]=>
  string(85) "struct GetDataWithParams {
  string command;
  string parameters;
  string tokenValue;
}"
[13]=>
  string(76) "struct GetDataWithParamsResponse {
  ResultGetData GetDataWithParamsResult;
}"
```

Comment: I just updated the original question with the example of what I tried.

Comment: Could we see how the relevant `$soapclient->__getFunctions()` & `$service->__getTypes()` look like? And the rule of thumb for PHP's Soapclient is: feed it _objects_ (or arrays) which the proper propertynames, not raw XML.

Comment: @Wrikken I've updated the original question but you might not have seen it, does this shed more light?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and errors I've finally got it working. Based on the documentation I figured I had to use **GetDataWithParams** method. So looking at the __getTypes result:

```
[12]=>
  string(85) "struct GetDataWithParams {
  string command;
  string parameters;
  string tokenValue;
}"
```

I figured command will be GetStock; tokenValue is $token. The part I couldn't work out was parameters, so I did some trial and errors and realised that it's expecting a string value: the raw xml code basically.

So what worked in the end was:

```
$params = new StdClass();
$params->command = 'GetStock';
$params->tokenValue = $token;
$params->parameters = "<params><ClientCode>{$this->clientCode}</ClientCode></params>";
```

Or in array format:

```
$params = array(
    'command' => 'GetStock',
    'tokenValue' => $token,
    'parameters' => "<params><ClientCode>{$this->clientCode}</ClientCode></params>",
    );
```

Thanks @Wrikken for pointing me in the right direction :)